# A conceptual understanding of kg*m/s/s

Tags: forces

Force is measured in kgm/s/s, or rather the rate in change of the rate in change of mass times length.

Conceptually, what might the product of mass and length be? If force is the second derivative of mass times length, that means force is the rate of change of the rate of change of mass times length; what, conceptually, really is mass times length? How would you represent it? Or is this a stupid question that arises out of a misunderstanding of our usage of units?

Answer (score 1):

Force is the mass times the rate of change of the rate of change of position (not length): 
$$
F=m\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)=m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2},\tag{1}
$$
which shows also that the force is the *mass* times the second derivative of *position*, rather than,
$$
F=x\frac{d^2m}{dt^2}\tag{2}
$$
so you've got your relationship backwards. You could also remember this by knowing that (a) $a=dv/dt$ and (b) $F=ma$ (which is how Newton wrote it) to get
$$
F=m\frac{dv}{dt}=m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\,.\tag{3}
$$
So clearly (1) and (3) match while (2) doesn't seem to have any meaning, even though the units "work out" (NB: I would not put much stock in analyzing things in terms if their units, otherwise you might think torque and energy are the same thing because their units are the same.).

The [National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_of_Standards_and_Technology) has a neat list of [derived SI units](http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/units.html). Perusing it, $\rm m\cdot kg$ does not appear together alone (there are terms that have m kg and factors of time in it).